# How do I use an image sensor with an arduino uno?

Tags: sensors

I have recently taken apart an old digital camera for its parts and I have found an image sensor inside it.

For those of you who don't know, an image sensor measures light; the shutter opens, light hits the sensor and the sensor converts this light into data to be stored as an image.

My question is how can I implement it into a project? What equipment do I need? It has a tape wire so I'm not really sure how I can use it. I have attached a photo of it also. Thanks!!

[image: Image of photo sensor]

Answer (score 1):

You need to find markings on it and figure out what the component actually is.  Then you can maybe find a datasheet for it that explains how it works and commmnicates.  Once you know that you can decide if that's something you can do with an Arduino.  Be prepared to learn that Arduino might not be big enough or fast enough to do anything with that particular sensor.

Comment: ARM based Arduinos probably are fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I implement it into a project?

Find its datasheet, understand how it works and code to it.

Just as what you would with any other devices. The challenge here is that you will be hard pressed to find any info about those kind of devices.